# match function or property not found in Lua script

Tags: lua

#### Issue description

facing an issue while calculating a new timestamp in Lua.
Error: `"match" function or property not found`

#### My Code

```
local myItem = syslib.getobject(myPath .. "/" .. "myVAR")
if myItem ~= nil then
local y, m, d, Hr, Min, Sec, Milli = myItem:match '(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+) (%d+):(%d+):(%d+).(%d+)'
local new_ts = os.time { year = y, month = m, day = d, hour = Hr, min = Min, sec = Sec } + 60*60
local next_time = string.format("%s.%03d", os.date("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", new_ts), Milli)
    syslib.setvalue(myItem, next_time)
else
   << code >>
end
```

Actually myItem will have timestamp like this '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000'.

please let me know do I need to declare anything to clear the issue?

Comment: `match` is a string function, but `myItem` isn't a string.

Answer (score 0):

it is resolved now by using `syslib.getvalue` instead of `syslib.getobject`.

```
local myItem = syslib.getvalue(myPath .. "/" .. "myVAR")
```